Problem with concurrency while updating data in DB using Quartz .NET and EF Core
I want to introduce horizontal scaling instead of vertical in my app.
Now we are using Quartz .NET for background tasks, but in non-clustered mode, just 1 instance.
So I found ability to do horizontal scaling using clustering. Then configured it in test app and found that 2 instances just attending "rat races" and updating every row twice.
Any ideas how can split load between many instances with quartz and ef core? How can I "lock" rows in DB, so that others instances cannot work with them and take next batch.
Code which I use to update DB and code of Quartz job provided below.
public async Task<int> UpdateNameAndMarkHiddenLogsAfterReachingDate(DateTime date)
    {
        const int batchSize = 10;
        int hidden = 0;
        int hiddenInThisLoopCycle;

        using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    var logs = await _context.Logs
                        .Where(l => l.Created < date && l.IsHidden == false)
                        .Take(batchSize).ToListAsync();

                    foreach (var log in logs)
                    {
                        log.Message = "UpdatedLog";
                        log.IsHidden = true;

                        log.LogDetails.Add(new LogDetail()
                        {
                            ChangedByThread = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId.ToString(),
                            LastChanged = DateTime.UtcNow,
                            Name = Thread.CurrentThread.Name
                        });
                    }

                    var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    hiddenInThisLoopCycle = result;

                    Console.WriteLine($"Deleted {hiddenInThisLoopCycle} logs.");
                    hidden += hiddenInThisLoopCycle;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Hidden: {hiddenInThisLoopCycle}");
                } while (hiddenInThisLoopCycle > 0);

                await transaction.CommitAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Transaction failed: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        return hidden;
    }

[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class DeleteLogsJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogRepository _logRepository;
    private readonly DateTime _date;
    private readonly ILogger<DeleteLogsJob> _logger;
    
    public DeleteLogsJob(ILogRepository logRepository, IOptions<DeleteLogsJobOptions> options, ILogger<DeleteLogsJob> logger)
    {
        _logRepository = logRepository;
        _date = options.Value.DeleteAfterDate ?? throw new ArgumentException("DeleteAfterDate was not found in configuration");
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("About to delete old logs from the database");
        var logsDeleted = await _logRepository.UpdateNameAndMarkHiddenLogsAfterReachingDate(_date);
        _logger.LogInformation("Deleted {0} old logs from the database", logsDeleted.ToString());
    }
}


Have you seen or tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908605/is-it-possible-to-use-database-first-ef-6-with-skip-locked-command
As far as I can see, this behaviour isn't quite reproducible with EF Core alone

One instance runs Quartz and determines the range of rows for each portion to process. Then calls  partition1 rows 1..1000 and partion2 1001..2000
